# What is 'uni_modal' for?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out what is uni_modal and I cant seem to find it on the internet

```
        $('.manage_percentage').click(function(){
            uni_modal('Manage Subject\'s Components Percentage',"manage_percentage.php?id="+$(this).attr('data-id'))
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

To best of my knowledge, **`uni_modal()` is not a standard function** from any standard library. It appears to be a **custom function defined somewhere in your codebase**.

The function seems to take two arguments: a string and a URL. However, without further context (the function definition), it is impossible to determine what the function does with these arguments.

Answer (score 0):

i've got the same situation and in one open source project couldn't find uni_modal() function so in many tries i wrote i think the same by myself and its working now. Changed function name to loadModal() when was working on it for omitting any DOM operations problems with old function uni_modal() when couldn't fidnd them in code.

```
$('.manage_progress').click(function(){
    loadModal("<i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Edit Progress","manage_progress.php?pid=<?php echo $id ?>&id="+$(this).attr('data-id'),'large')
}) 
function loadModal(title, url, size) {
// create modal
var modal = document.createElement('div');
modal.className = 'modal';

// load modal content from URL
modal.innerHTML = '<div class="modal-dialog modal-' + size + '">' +
                      '<div class="modal-content">' +
                          '<div class="modal-header">' +
                              '<h5 class="modal-title">' + title + '</h5>' +
                              '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>' +
                          '</div>' +
                          '<div class="modal-body"></div>' +
                      '</div>' +
                  '</div>';

// Add modal to site
document.body.appendChild(modal);

// load context to  modal-body via fetch or AJAX
fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
        modal.querySelector('.modal-body').innerHTML = data;
        $(modal).modal('show'); // Initialize modal with jQuery
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Modal loading error:', error));
}
```

just change uni_modal() to loadModal() and paste rest of the code below manage_percentage

Answer (score 0):

It's a function elsewhere defined in your code (perhaps in another file).

You can find the function definition yourself by right-clicking `uni_modal` in the debugger (after breaking at the line your showed) and selecting "Show function definition", or by entering `uni_modal` in the browser console and clicking the source link on the right.